# Help me with mercurial extension exportfiles

Tags: python, mercurial, tortoisehg

i'm trying to use [exportfiles](http://bitbucket.org/albert_brand/hgexportfiles/) extension for mercurial but I'm getting this error:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\dev>hg exportfiles -r 1 /tmp/export
** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
**  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9+10-e9264b45237d)
** Extensions loaded: exportfiles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 42, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 27, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 64, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 87, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 675, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 454, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 729, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 683, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 672, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 385, in check
  File "C:\Users\Sasa/exportfiles.py", line 39, in exportfiles
    rng = cmdutil.revrange(repo, opts['rev'])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'revrange'
```

I'm using TortiseHG 2.1.1 for Windows 32-bit with Mercurial 1.9+10

Could you help me please to solve this and use exportfiles extension?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mercurial's API changed after version 1.8.](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ApiChanges#Changes_after_1.8)

> Various functions have been moved from cmdutil.py to scmutil.py,
>   including revrange/revsingle/revpair and match/matchall/matchfiles

Assuming [this](https://bitbucket.org/albert_brand/hgexportfiles/src/ac8754d1d7ef/exportfiles.py) is the source of the extension you're using, line 11 should be

```
from mercurial import util, scmutil
```

and line 39 should be

```
rng = scmutil.revrange(repo, opts['rev'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine now. I'm created pull request on the repo with this changes and hope that author will accept it soon.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Mercurial's internals have changed a bit and the extension needs to be updated, however I'm not entirely what's wrong. <strike>`cmdutil` does seem to have a `revrange` method.</strike> *NB: The place where I saw the source for `cmdutil` was evidently an out-of-date fork.*

However, until someone chimes in with a fix to the extension, there is a workaround for at least getting a list of files added or modified. You can transform the output or feed it to your own script in order to get the right files copied:

```
hg status --rev 100:110 --added --modified
```

This lists files added or modified from revision 100 to revision 110 (you can't use `-r` as a shortened switch of `--rev`, it's short for `--removed`). The output has a `M` or `A` before each relative path.

Comment: I am almost positive that your hypothesis is correct. Mercurial 1.9 has had a lot of API churn from previous 1.8.x versions, and the Mercurial people even [posted a note when releasing [TortoiseHg 2.1](http://mercurial.markmail.org/message/btmsdhg56z2ga4qn?q=list:com%2Eselenic%2Emercurial+churn+1%2E9+extensions) about this. If the extension hasn't been updated I would expect the problem to be related to this.